# Android: Action based on combination of two spinner selections

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-spinner, android-image

I have an activity with two spinners. One is the type of hair and the other is the color of the hair. I want for a picture (on a head) to change based on the two items selected selected from the spinners.

Here's what it should do:

1. Activity loaded (Spinners set to "Bald" and "Black")

   - Hair is bald.
2. Change hair type to 'Male Short'

   - Hair changes to short black male hair.
3. Change color to 'Blonde'

   - Hair changes to short blonde male hair.

But step 3 doesn't work!!!

Heres my code:

```
public class HeadZoom extends MainActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

private Spinner hairSpinner;
private Spinner hairColor;
private String type;
private String color;
private ImageView imageView;
private List<String> hairTypeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> hairColorArray = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.head_zoom);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.head);
    type="Bald";

    hairSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hairSpinner);
    hairSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> hairTypeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    hairTypeArray.add("Bald");
    hairTypeArray.add("Female Short");
    hairTypeArray.add("Female Medium");
      (...)
    ArrayAdapter<String> hairTypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hairTypeArray);
    hairTypeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    hairSpinner.setAdapter(hairTypeAdapter);

    color = "Black";

    hairColor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hairColor);
    hairColor.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    List<String> hairColorArray = new ArrayList<>();
    hairColorArray.add("Black");
    hairColorArray.add("Blonde");
    hairColorArray.add("Blue");
      (...)
    ArrayAdapter<String> hairColorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hairColorArray);
    hairColorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    hairColor.setAdapter(hairColorAdapter);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
    if(parent.getId()==hairSpinner.getId())
        type = hairTypeArray.get(position);
    else
        color = hairColorArray.get(position);

    switch(type){
        case "Bald":
            imageView.setImageResource((R.drawable.sw_head));
            break;
        case "Female Short":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_short_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                (...)
                break;
        case "Female Medium":
            if(color=="Black")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_black);
            else if(color=="Blonde")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_blonde);
            else if(color=="Blue")
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fhair_med_blue);
            else if(color=="Brown")
                (...)
                break;
        case "Female Long":
               (...)
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent){

}
```

I need to be able to know what has been selected on both spinners at the same time.

I get this error report when the activity (btw it crashes as soon as the activity opens)

```
    04-27 15:39:17.165 9934-9934/cameron.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: cameron.myapplication, PID: 9934
                                                                 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                     at cameron.myapplication.HeadZoom.onItemSelected(HeadZoom.java:83)
                                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:931)
                                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:920)
                                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(AdapterView.java)
                                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:890)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: both the array size is same?

Comment: @sasikumar Yes, both of them have 7 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is  **already you Initialized** ArrayList in global .

```
 private List<String> hairTypeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
 private List<String> hairColorArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

so out of oncreate method its take only global variable values.but you added values only local arraylist oncreate method.so remove the following code in oncreate method

```
List<String> hairColorArray = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> hairTypeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Can't believe I didn't spot this. I haven't worked on this project for almost a month because I just couldn't work out what was wrong. I owe you big time!

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are comparing two String objects with == operator. If == operator is used between two String object it will check if both string have same reference irrespective of value they hold.

You need to compare like this:

```
if(color.equalsIgnoreCase("Black"))
```

OR

```
if(color.equals("Black"))
```

this will check for String object value instead of its reference.

As @sasikumar suggested also remove that Local Variables

```
List<String> hairColorArray = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> hairTypeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
```